# What do you call the place in cinemas or theatres when you can leave your clothes?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call the place cinemas or theatres when you can leave your clothes. Can I call it a *dress room*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online Merriam Webster Dictionary defines [cloakroom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloakroom) as

> a room in which outdoor clothing may be placed during one's stay

It also gives [checkroom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/checkroom) as an alternative definition.

Merriam Webster is an American dictionary and 'checkroom' is not a word I, as a British English speaker, recognise but it seems that 'cloakroom' is valid in both dialects. Admittedly 'cloakroom' is sometimes used as a euphemism for 'toilet' in the UK but the any room labelled 'cloakroom' in the UK is a place to leave outer clothing.

'Dress room' is not a valid term for a cloakroom as, normally, only outdoor clothing is left in a cloakroom, not indoor clothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you may be thinking of is generally known as a "coat check room" (where you can leave your coat, etc, and they give you a ticket so you can pick it up again later (after the show is over)).

Comment: Outside America, it may well be called the 'cloakroom'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It's often called that in America too, especially at "classier" venues where such rooms are most common.

Comment: There is a type of printed ticket that in Britain is called a [cloakroom ticket](https://outlet.malgra.co.uk/product/cloakroom-tickets-1-to-1000-1-box/). They come in 'books' - each ticket has two identical parts and is perforated so it can be split. One part is given to the customer, the other is pinned to the hat, coat, etc. The item(s) can usually only be reclaimed by production of the customer portion. These books of tickets are also used for other purposes e.g. a type of small local lottery called a 'raffle'.